# Add onclick handler from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My goal is to set a click handler from my extension to a button with id ='myBtn'
How do I do this?

**The button is outside of my extension**

This is what i've come so far:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", click_func);
});

click_func(){
    alert(1)
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Where is this button ? Is it in one of your extension's pages or is it outside of your extension.

Comment: @Titus outside.

Comment: In that case, you'll need a content script, you can learn more about that [HERE](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)